# How to publish to an IoT MQTT topic from a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I'm attempting to trigger an IoT event via Alexa. I've created an Alexa skill which triggers a Lambda written in Go, which publishes an event to SNS. However, I can't see of a way to get an IoT device to listen to an SNS event.

Similarly, there doesn't seem to be a Go library for IoT, so I can't get the Lambda to interact directly with the IoT MQTT protocol as a client either.

I just wondered if I'd need to re-write my Lambda as a JS Lambda for the purposes of interacting with the IoT core, or if there was a better way to trigger an IoT event from a Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to publish to an IoT topic from within your Lambda function via the [IoTDataPlane.Publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/iotdataplane/#IoTDataPlane.Publish) method in the [AWS SDK for Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/).

Comment: Ahhh fantastic, great find. Thank you!